# How to configure log4j 1.2 using xml

Tags: xml, log4j

I am stuck with legacy code that uses log4j 1.2.12, and am trying to resolve some errors it is throwing about appenders. I cannot find documentation for log4j 1.2 - I keep getting redirected to log4j 2. Nice, but not helpful. The main documentation for 1.2 doesn't have any sample xml. If anybody can point me to good documentation on this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: While http://logging.apache.org/log4j now redirects to log4j 2, the 1.2 pages are still available at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/

Comment: @IanRoberts - Yeah, but there's nothing in there about xml configuration other than a casual reference to the fact that you can do it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The original documentation was available at http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat

The wiki is in maintenance at the moment, so I cannot verify that the link is still valid. You will find the document at archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20121024061840/http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat